# React big calendar between time on time slots

Tags: reactjs, react-big-calendar

I have used the resource scheduler of React big calendar and I wondered if the intermediate steps of the time slots could also be made transparent, but that the overview remains.

This is currently my result:
[image]

With this code:

```
import React , {useEffect} from "react";
import { useState } from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

import styles from "assets/jss/material-dashboard-react/views/dashboardStyle.js";
import { Container } from "react-bootstrap";
import { Row } from "react-bootstrap";
import { Col } from "react-bootstrap";


import 'react-big-calendar/lib/css/react-big-calendar.css'
import { Calendar, momentLocalizer, Views } from 'react-big-calendar'
import moment from 'moment';
import 'moment/locale/nl';
import Firebase from 'firebase';

moment.locale('nl');

const localizer = momentLocalizer(moment);

const newEvents = [];

export default function CalendarDesk() {

    const [eventDb, setEventDb] = useState([]);


    useEffect(() => {
      let ref = Firebase.database().ref('/events');
    ref.on('value' , snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach((childSnap) => {
        let state = childSnap.val();
        console.log(state);
            //newEvents.push({title: state.title, id: state.id, resourceId: state.resourceId,start: new Date(state.yearStart,state.monthStart,state.dayStart,state.hourStart,state.minuteStart,state.secondStart),end: new Date(state.yearStart,state.monthStart,state.dayStart,state.hourEnd,state.minuteEnd,state.secondEnd)}); 
            setEventDb(eventDb => [...eventDb,{title: state.title, id: state.id, resourceId: state.resourceId,start: new Date(state.yearStart,state.monthStart,state.dayStart,state.hourStart,state.minuteStart,state.secondStart),end: new Date(state.yearStart,state.monthStart,state.dayStart,state.hourEnd,state.minuteEnd,state.secondEnd)}]);          
    });
  })

  console.log(newEvents);

  },[] );

      const resourceMap = [
        { resourceId: 1, resourceTitle: 'Robin Frissen' },
        { resourceId: 2, resourceTitle: 'Raoul Frissen' },
        { resourceId: 3, resourceTitle: 'Joppe Meijers' },

      ]

      let today = new Date();
      let formats ={
        timeGutterFormat: (date, culture, localizer) => 
              localizer.format(date, 'H:mm', culture),
      }

      const onSelectEvent = function(pEvent) {
        const r = window.confirm("Weet je zeker dat je de afspraak wilt verwijderen?'")
        if(r === true){
          //const idx = indexOf(pEvent)
          console.log(pEvent);
          var ref = Firebase.database().ref('events');
          ref.orderByChild('id').equalTo(pEvent.id).on('child_added', (snapshot) => {
          snapshot.ref.remove()
          });

          setEventDb(eventDb.filter(item => item.id !== pEvent.id));


        }
      }

  return (
    <div>
      <Container>
          <h3>Agenda</h3>
          <Row >
            <Col md={12} >


                <Calendar
                events={eventDb}
                localizer={localizer}
                defaultView={'day'}
                views ={['day', 'work_week']}
                timeslots={4}
                step={15}
                defaultDate={new Date()}
                formats={formats}
                onSelectEvent = {event => onSelectEvent(event)}
                min={new Date(today.getFullYear(),today.getMonth(), today.getDate(), 8)}
                max={new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate(), 18)}
                resources={resourceMap}
                resourceIdAccessor="resourceId"
                resourceTitleAccessor="resourceTitle"
                culture={moment.locale('nl')}
                messages={{
                  today: "Vandaag",
                  previous: "<",
                  next: ">",
                  month: "Maand",
                  week: "Week",
                  day: "Dag"
                }}
                />

            </Col>
        </Row>

        </Container>
    </div>
  );

}
```

And this would be the desired result:
[image]

I know that by ->

`timeslots={1} step={10}`

I can add more slots, but this is not clear because everything is placed under the same size under each other.